# Facebook Send Private message

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

How can I write a private message in Facebook via iPhone app? I saw program on iPad it's called "Friendly".. It seems that they not using Graph API, but then how??? 
Any help please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook api currently only allows you to prompt for "[read_mailbox](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)" permissions.  It doesn't allow for write permissions.  If Friendly is able to send messages, it got special whitelisting permissions from Facebook, or they are violating Facebook's terms of services and are doing some form of scraping.